# How do I allow a particular firestore user account access to a document created by another user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to come up with a secure system that allows read access for a user to a particular document created by another user. I am trying to think my way through the security rules, but I am unsure of the implementation. Ideally, the owner of the document would provide permission for another user to "read" any updates and changes to this document

At the moment, I am creating a random string and creating a document with that string. The user then has the opportunity to share this with another user (via text or some other mechanism for example). If the other user had the string (session ID) then they can enter that into their view and then read any updates that the user makes in real-time.

The issue is that I can't guarantee that the session ID is unique and I am sure that this is not very secure. I think I need to create a document and create a value in that document with the session ID. Again, not sure how to make sure that the session ID is unique among all of the other documents.

I am just not sure what the best way to implement this securely. Thanks in advance for any help our guidance.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague for Stack Overflow.  I suggest editing the question to discuss what your intended documents look like, the code you're using to read and write them, and a first attempt at expressing security rules, even if they don't work the way you expect.

Comment: OK, I will have another go. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit broad so let me provide a broad suggestion.

Start with a structure

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Hank"
   uid_1
      name: "Frank"
   uid_2
      name: "Lenny"
```

and suppose users can craft documents and share them with others

```
documents
   doc_0
      title "hanks document"
      owner: uid_0
```

and Hank shares his document with Frank so update the node that determines which users can access which documents:

```
shared_rules
   uid_0
       doc_0
          shared_with
             uid_1: true
```

In this case when Hank (uid_0) shares a document with Frank (uid_0) a child is added to the shared_rules for uid_0. We use the document Id as a key so the rules know which document it is.

Only uid_0 can write to that node but others can read from it and the rules would simply verify that uid_0/doc_0/shared_with/uid_1 exists, if so, allow doc_0 to be read by uid_1. If not, no read is allowed.

There's about 100 other options but perhaps that will point you in the right direction for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I will look into this method, really helpful idea, I am just getting used to firebase.